# How to delete comments when using a screen reader?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

According to 
[the answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work):

> A user may delete one of his own comments by clicking on the (x) icon that appears to the right of the comment's timestamp when the comment is moused over.

To anyone using screen readers, how to access this (x) icon to click it? I am using JAWS 16.0 with firefox.

Or are there other ways to do this aside from clicking this (x) icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon is also link. With a title that says "delete this comment".

Click the link if you want to delete the comment that just preceded it.

---

Now that we clarified that the issue is that the "link" doesn't have any text for the screen reader to read, I am classing this as a bug.

<strike>I have a fix ready which will be out in the next build (rev 2014.11.11.2010, meta rev 2014.11.11.2743)</strike>.

I have an actual fix ready which will be out in the next build (rev 2014.11.11.2012, meta rev 2014.11.11.2745)

Comment: For example, this comment will have a link after it that will delete it (well, for me and for moderators).

Comment: @recursivePointer - of course it does (that is, of course you don't have the link). You are not me, nor are you a moderator. You will not have that link on my comments. Though you should have it on _yours_, just before this one.

Comment: Do you not get an "edit" link after the comment? The delete link is just after that one.

Comment: What screen reader software are you using?

Comment: JAWS, sometimes NVDA. Both did not read the link.

Comment: Could be on account of it being empty (only a bunch of spaces). Fixing this will require a code change, though I am not sure what that would be exactly. Looking into this.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you mind deleting the comments I posted in the first answer to this question so I can post a new comment that is not confusing? Thanks again. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69402/simple-stack-implementation-using-linked-list

Comment: I have deleted both comments there for you. Sorry this has been such a hassle for you - I will make sure we fix it.

Comment: You should be able to see a delete link at the end of your comments now - can you confirm this is the case and that the link works for you?

Comment: I still can't read it. I tried deleting all my previous comments above to test but I still can't find it. I tried this on JAWS and NVDA. Please note that I can read the "edit" link directly after my comment before 5 minutes where I think it should disappear. No luck on "delete" though.

Comment: Did you refresh the page?

Comment: Yep, I just refreshed it.

Comment: Weight, I just read it! But when I press enter on it to try to delete one comment the "delete" disappears? I've been refreshing the page and I can't find it again.

Comment: The attempted fix didn't really work - we are reworking it to be something that does. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @Oded! I just managed to delete some comments. Looks like it's working now, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @recursivePointer - excellent!